# You know I told you

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

*You know I told you my car wouldn't start?*

Is the "you know I told you" part perfectly natural and commonly used?

Would it mean exactly the same as "you remember I told you...?"

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Please check the HELP section (top right of your screen), to see which questions are valid here. Thanks. You know I, You remember I, You think I, You said I. etc.

Comment: Ideally, that sentence would be: "You know/remember **how** I told you *this thing*?"

Comment: @myacorn that wouldn't sound natural to this brit at all